# Cropping a variable width frame with graphicsmagick

Tags: image-processing, graphicsmagick

I have some images that have a transparent border of varying width; I'd like to crop these to the visible parts of image. (I imagine a solution won't be specific to the *transparent* part, but would work with a frame of any color.)

E.g. the 200x200 image below has a transparent border of 3 pixels. I'd like to get the equivalent of

```
$ gm convert a.png -crop 194x194+3+3 b.png
```

without having to determine the numbers by hand. Is this possible with graphicsmagick (or imagemagick)?

[image: sample]

Comment: Have you tried `gm convert input.png -fuzz 10% -trim result.png`?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I didn't know about trim, no! Works perfectly, thank you.